# Javascript create custom event with cancelation on return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, cancellation, custom-events

I would like to create a custom event that tests if any registered handler return false, and cancel an action if any one does.

I have two types of object, (one or more) Page(s) and (one) Navigator.

Navigator registeres user attempts on leaving the page, but it has no knowledge about what is on the page or pages. The Page object knows the content of the page, but have no knowledge about when the user try to leave the page.

I want the Navigator to emmit a beforepageleave event that all Page objects could listen for, and if the beforepageleave handler in all Pages returns true Navigator should continue its business, but if any Page handler returns false, it should just cancel the navigation and stay on the page.

Page has a hasChanges attribute that should stop Navigator if it is true.

So the handler in Page could in a simplified form look something like:

```
navigator.on('beforepageleave', function (e) { return !this.hasChanges; });
```

The navigator method could simplified look something like this:

```
leavePageLinks.click(function (e) {
    let proceed = true;
    $.each(registeredEventHandlers, function (index, handler) {
        if (!handler(e)) {
            proceed = false;
        }
    }
    return proceed;
});
```

I have seen that jQuery saves eventhandlers in (jQuery._data || jQuery.data)(elem, 'events'), but I would prefer to use non private methods and not rely on code that might change completely without my knowledge. Also, I'm not sure I should override the handling like this at all?